# Mysql backup from a mounted root drive

Tags: mysql, linux

I had a problem with my hdd. There is a new system running in place and I found that I can mount and access the / of my old hdd (It had a Debian Linux distribution). However I forgot to backup some important data in the DB tables and I was wondering if there was anyway to execute a mysql server command from the mysql server installation in the mounted drive?

Comment: If the files are ok, access to MyISAM tables could simply done by copying or creating symlinks to the old hdd. InnoDB tables are more difficult to handle, see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6268/how-to-recover-an-innodb-table-whose-files-were-moved-around/6269#6269. I would recommend to take a backup of the data directories first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your hdd contains complete OS, you can simply mount it and chroot to it. In chrooted environment start your mysql server and take data-backup with mysqldump command.

Or you can simply install mysql-server on your new system, change data directory option in /etc/my.cnf to the mounted partition, backup the data with mysqldump command. You can then revert the my.cnf change back.

Comment: Used the first option. Worked like a charm. Thank you!